# save image file using SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sqldatasource

How to pass byte array as update parameter in SqlDataSource control?

```
Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value as you do with normal parameter value, however you have to Set `Type="Object"`

```
<UpdateParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="" Type="Object" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: like this ? sqlDataSource.UpdateParameters["Image1"].DefaultValue = bytes;

Comment: yes but as I have mentioned, its Type should be object and there is nothing you have to special, are you getting any issue by doing this ?

Comment: now after saving the file .how will retrieve the binary data from the database and show as image on my aspx page

Comment: To show image, you can check this url http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html    http://odetocode.com/articles/172.aspx

Comment: sqlDataSource.UpdateParameters["Image1"].DefaultValue = bytes; is giving me a error "Cannot Implicitly convert byte[] to string"

Comment: sqlDataSource.UpdateParameters["Image1"].DefaultValue = (Byte[]) bytes;